# MQTT connection passed as a property doen't work for Subscribe and disconnect

Tags: jmeter, mqtt, publish-subscribe, jmx, jmeter-plugins

I am using MQTT messages as a prerequisite . Hence its sufficient to make one connection which is shared between thread groups.

I tried to save connection as a property and it works absolutely fine for Publish however subscribe and disconnect fails .

Code for Connection as a Property
`props.put('connection', vars.getObject('conn'))`
`vars.putObject('conn', props.get('connection'))`

Subscribe Error

```
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936) ~[?:?]
    at net.xmeter.samplers.SubSampler.sample(SubSampler.java:136) ~[mqtt-xmeter-2.0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
```

Disconnect error

`Response code:501 Response message:Failed to disconnect Connection`

Answer (score -1):

We cannot comprehensively answer [without seeing your](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

1. [Test plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan)
2. [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)
3. The values of the associated properties (can be observed using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) combination

In general sharing data between Thread Groups is an edge case, you should rather stick to a single Thread Group like it's shown in [Example JMeter Scripts](https://github.com/emqx/mqtt-jmeter#example-jmeter-scripts) or in [How to Test the MQTT Messaging Broker](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/test-mqtt)

So if you're running 1 thread - you can put everything into a single thread group. If you're running multiple threads - make sure that each thread has its own connection as it seems you're trying to close connection which has been already closed.